# Xamarin.Mac handle incoming URLs

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I have added url in my Info.plist and trying to handle incoming url like described in this [article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app).

I'm trying to add this code

```
        public override void WillFinishLaunching(NSNotification notification)
        {
            NSAppleEventManager.SharedAppleEventManager.SetEventHandler(this, new ObjCRuntime.Selector("handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:"), AEEventClass.Internet, AEEventID.GetUrl);
        }    

        [Export("handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:")]
        private void HandleGetURLEvent(NSAppleEventDescriptor descriptor, NSAppleEventDescriptor replyEvent)
        {
            Logger.Info("Calling url on running app");
        }
```

It all works fine, when my application is launched and somebody clicks on a URL (containing this custom scheme).

However, in the case, if my app isn't started then system start is (which is good). Unfortunately, handleGetURL() isn't called.

Comment: Your link  to application(_:open:options:) references UIApplicationDelegate which is the iOS version. If you lookup NSApplicationDelegate you will find that the top override method in the popuplist is the correct one

Comment: I edited my question. Please see original post. If my app isn't started then system start is (which is good). Unfortunately, handleGetURL() isn't called

Comment: Do you mean you want requests to those URLs activate your app automatically if it is not yet running?

Comment: I want if my app isn't started then and somebody clicks on a URL (containing this custom scheme) after starting my app then will be calling method HandleGetURLEvent. Now HandleGetURLEvent isn't called.

Comment: This could be a potential issue and I see you posted an issue:[handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent isn't called when app isn't started](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/16767) in Github, you can continue following up.